# Cassandra shutting down because of org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.1

Canssandra (2.1.13) on startup throwing "org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException"

Here is the stacktrace:

> ERROR [MemtableFlushWriter:1] 2018-10-22 03:24:41,191
>   CassandraDaemon.java:229 - Exception in thread
>   Thread[MemtableFlushWriter:1,5,main]
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError:
>   java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
>
> /var/data/system/schema_columnfamilies-45f5b36024bc3f83a3631034ea4fa697/system-schema_columnfamilies-tmp-ka-60-Digest.sha1
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DataIntegrityMetadata$ChecksumWriter.writeFullChecksum(DataIntegrityMetadata.java:155)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedSequentialWriter.writeFullChecksum(CompressedSequentialWriter.java:285)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.close(SSTableWriter.java:518)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.finish(SSTableWriter.java:455)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.closeAndOpenReader(SSTableWriter.java:447)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.closeAndOpenReader(SSTableWriter.java:442)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.writeSortedContents(Memtable.java:389)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.runMayThrow(Memtable.java:335)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
>   ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$Flush.run(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1120)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>
> Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
>   /var/data/system/schema_columnfamilies-45f5b36024bc3f83a3631034ea4fa697/system-schema_columnfamilies-tmp-ka-60-Digest.sha1
>           at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>           at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>           at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>           at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>           at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>           at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>           at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter(Files.java:2860) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DataIntegrityMetadata$ChecksumWriter.writeFullChecksum(DataIntegrityMetadata.java:150)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           ... 13 common frames omitted
>
> ERROR [CompactionExecutor:1] 2018-10-22 03:24:41,192
>   CassandraDaemon.java:229 - Exception in thread
>   Thread[CompactionExecutor:1,1,main] java.lang.RuntimeException: Tried
>   to hard link to file that does not exist
>   /var/data/system/schema_keyspaces-b0f2235744583cdb9631c43e59ce3676/system-schema_keyspaces-tmp-ka-65-Index.db
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createHardLink(FileUtils.java:90)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.makeTmpLinks(SSTableWriter.java:390)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.finish(SSTableWriter.java:460)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.switchWriter(SSTableRewriter.java:398)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.finishAndMaybeThrow(SSTableRewriter.java:453)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.finish(SSTableRewriter.java:435)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.finish(SSTableRewriter.java:415)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.runMayThrow(CompactionTask.java:214)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.executeInternal(CompactionTask.java:73)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionTask.execute(AbstractCompactionTask.java:59)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$BackgroundCompactionCandidate.run(CompactionManager.java:263)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_181]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
>
> ERROR [MemtableFlushWriter:1] 2018-10-22 03:24:41,192
>   StorageService.java:453 - Stopping gossiper WARN 
>   [MemtableFlushWriter:1] 2018-10-22 03:24:41,193
>   StorageService.java:359 - Stopping gossip by operator request INFO 
>   [MemtableFlushWriter:1] 2018-10-22 03:24:41,193 Gossiper.java:1455 -
>   Announcing shutdown

Found one related link https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204424739-Apache-Cassandra-fails-to-start-with-FSReadError-and-java-io-EOFException- but this talks about FSReadError whereas in above stack trace the issue is FSWriteError wherein the file doesn't exist.

Is this some setup related issue or known issue which can be fixed or is it version specific?

If not wrong then these tmp files are being generated at compaction time and resulting into issues. Currently not able to proceed here and looking for pointers here.

Thanks!

Comment: does `/var/data/system/schema_columnfamilies-45f5b36024bc3f83a3631034ea4fa697` exist? does the user running cassandra have read/write access to it?

Comment: Yes, the directory exists and user has read/write access to it. Saw other links where there was AccessDenied exception logged but in this case it is NoSuchFileException exception. Actually one more observation here, when tried again this issue is not seen and it succeeds. However this issue is intermittent and not sure what could be the reason.

Comment: you don't have antivirus running on that node?

Comment: No, there is no antivirus running.